# Uploading videos on rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, devise, ffmpeg, paperclip

I am trying to let my users upload videos on my website(not deployed yet, testing locally). I have it set up in a manner where if the "user information" gets saved, it will take them to the "root_path", which is the homepage. If the user information is not saved, it will render the form again. Before I added the video upload feature, all the information got saved and everything worked well, but after adding the feature, it keeps rendering the same form over and over again since the information is not getting saved. How do I check what's wrong? The command line gives me this error: [image: Error screenshot]

The user information form partial:
`

```
<%= simple_form_for @userinfo do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: 'Full name', error: 'Full name is mandatory' %>
  <%= f.input :username, label: 'Username', error: 'Username is mandatory, please specify one' %>
  <%= f.input :school, label: 'Name of college' %>
  <%= f.input :gpa, label: 'Enter GPA' %>
  <%= f.input :email, label: 'Enter email address' %>
  <%= f.input :number, label: 'Phone number' %>
  <%= f.file_field :video %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

`

My user controller (This is the user information controller, does not control user email and password. I'm using the devise gem for user sign in, sign out, and sign up):`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @userinfo = User.new
    end

    def create
        @userinfo = User.new(user_params)
        if @userinfo.save
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private
        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :email, :number, :school, :gpa, :major, :video)
        end
end
```

`

This is the user model (usermain is the model related to user password and email. The user information in the user model belongs to the usermain): `

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :usermain

    has_attached_file :video, styles: {:video_show => {:geometry => "640x480",:format => 'mp4'},:video_index => { :geometry => "160x120", :format => 'jpeg', :time => 10}}, :processors => [:transcoder]
    validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
end
```

`

This is the migration file that creates the user information table:`

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :number
      t.string :school
      t.string :gpa
      t.string :major

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

`This is adding the "video" field to the above created user information table:`

```
class AddAttachmentVideoToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.attachment :video
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :users, :video
  end
end
```

`

I also have paperclip and ffmpeg installed. When I say installed, it's literally just that. I'm not sure if I have to manipulate paperclip or ffmpeg in any way to make it work with the videos, I have just installed and did nothing else with them. I have been pulling my hair out for the past two days. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add `puts @userinfo.errors.full_messages` to your controller and report back with the results.

Comment: You say you're using devise, but I don't see any devise code in your `User` model. Add your Gemfile changes and remove the image. It was useless to you, it's useless to us without validation messages. Why all the blank useless code in controller code? Why isn't the bulk of your question about Paperclip? You say **all** you did is "installed" I assume you mean add the gem and bundle and some basic usage? What have you tried? What are your resources, references or articles?

Comment: @fbelanger please let me know what other information I can provide in order to get a solution.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @fbelanger Hey man, the reason you don't see any devise code in the user model is because the user model is not associated with devise. I have a different model called usermain which is associated with devise. User model just handles the user information like name, school, gpa... and so on. The empty functions in the controller are because I will be adding stuff to it later. The reason the whole question is not about paperclip is because I don't know if paperclip is the issue, that is the reason I asked the question in the first place. Because I don't know what's causing the issue